# Get class from inside a each()

Tags: jquery

I have something like this. I would like to extract the values of classes `BarA` and `BarB` of each class

```
<div class="foo>
  <div class="dprop">
     <div class="BarA"> </div>
     <div class="BarB"> </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="foo>
  <div class="dprop">
     <div class="BarA"> </div>
     <div class="BarB"> </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am doing this to iterate over all the `foo` classes

```
 $(".foo").each(function () {
        //How to get innerHtml of BarA and BarB ?
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

To do what you require you can target the child div of `.foo .dprop` and loop over them using `each()` and `text()`:

```js
$(".foo .dprop > div").each((i, el) => {
  let text = $(el).text();
  // do something with the text here...
  console.log(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="foo">
  <div class="dprop">
     <div class="BarA">BarA-1</div>
     <div class="BarB">BarB-1</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="foo">
  <div class="dprop">
     <div class="BarA">BarA-2</div>
     <div class="BarB">BarB-2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Alternatively you can use `map()` to build an array of their text content to be used at a later point in your logic:

```js
let values = $(".foo .dprop > div").map((i, el) => el.textContent).get();
console.log(values);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="foo">
  <div class="dprop">
     <div class="BarA">BarA-1</div>
     <div class="BarB">BarB-1</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="foo">
  <div class="dprop">
     <div class="BarA">BarA-2</div>
     <div class="BarB">BarB-2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you tell me what this selector does ? `.foo .dprop > div`

Comment: *what this selector does* - see https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/

Comment: Also, given that jQuery uses CSS rules, see this list: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors

Answer (score 0):

First change `<div class="foo>` to `<div class="foo">`. To get `innerHTML` you can use either:

```
$('.selector').each((i, element) => {
    console.log( element.innerHTML );
});
```

Which is similar to:

```
$('.selector').each(function() {
    console.log( this.innerHTML );
});
```

OR:

```
$('.selector').each((i,element) => {
    console.log( $(element).html() );
});
```

Where `.selector` is

> `.foo .dprop > div` OR

> `.foo > .dprop > div` OR

> `.BarA,.BarB`

**NOTE**

`> div` is necessary since the elements `div.BarA` and `div.BarB` may have `div` descendants, and you just want to target only `div` elements that children of `.dprop`.
The last one assumes the `div.BarA` and `div.BarB` do themselves have any descendants with the classes.

```js
$('.foo > .dprop > div').each((i, element) => console.log( element.innerHTML ));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="foo">
  <div class="dprop">
     <div class="BarA"><span>Text BarA1</span></div>
     <div class="BarB"><span>Text BarB1</span></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="foo">
  <div class="dprop">
     <div class="BarA"><span>Text BarA2</span></div>
     <div class="BarB"><span>Text BarB2</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```